# Вопрос по Tesseract.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract

Всем привет. Использую библиотеку [Tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js) на *node js* и код из примера работает, но когда я попытался использовать его в боте, он начал выдавать ошибку, но потом я пихнул его под *setInterval*, и оно выдаёт ту же самую ошибку. Может кто знает в чём проблема.

Вот код:

```
setInterval(async () => {
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage(langs);
    await worker.initialize(langs);
    const {data: {text}} = await worker.recognize('./2.jpg');
    console.log('Text is reading')
    console.log(text);
    await worker.terminate();
}, 5000);
```

И после он первый раз срабатывает и выводит результат, а во второй раз выводит:

```
(node:10888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
    at module.exports (C:\Users\RIXIN\Desktop\tesseractNode\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\worker\node\send.js:9:10)
    at C:\Users\RIXIN\Desktop\tesseractNode\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:47:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at startJob (C:\Users\RIXIN\Desktop\tesseractNode\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:43:5)
    at Object.load (C:\Users\RIXIN\Desktop\tesseractNode\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:57:5)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\RIXIN\Desktop\tesseractNode\index.js:18:18)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:10888) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/400#issuecomment-581126862

Answer (score 0):

В коде просто нужно убрать `await worker.terminate();`

Вот исправленный код:

```js
setInterval(async () => {
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage(langs);
    await worker.initialize(langs);
    const {data: {text}} = await worker.recognize('./2.jpg');
    console.log('Text is reading')
    console.log(text);
}, 5000);
```